# How can I concatenate ' in a string using python

Tags: python, append, concatenation

I am trying to add ' at the end and beginning of the string.
I have

```
str1 = 'abc'
str2 = 'def'
strf = str1 + str2
print strf
```

It gives output

```
   abcdef
```

I need `'abcdef'`

I have tried join

```
'''.join(strf)
```

what I am trying to achieve here is the variable will be passed to parse an xml, where strf is the path of the xml, so it shouls have ' at the beginning and end.
doc = ET.parse(strf)

PLease advise what will be best solution.
Thanks in advance.
Urmi

Comment: A string always has quotes around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A string always has quotes around it, without quotes it's not a string.

Use `repr` to see the quotes,  `print` always shows the string without quote:

```
>>> str1 = 'abc'
>>> str2 = 'def'
>>> print str1 + str2
abcdef                     #just a human friendly output, the string still have quotes
>>> print repr(str1 + str2)
'abcdef'
```

Another alternative is string formatting:

```
>>> strf = str1 + str2
>>> print "'{}'".format(strf)
'abcdef'
```

Comment: Or simply type `str1 + str2` at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
print "'%s'" % strf
```

Or even:

```
print "'" + strf + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, none of them particularly tricky:

```
strf = "'" + str1 + str2 + "'"
strf = "'%s%s'"%(str1, str2)
strf = "'{0}{1}'".format(str1, str2)
strf = "".join([ "'", str1, str2, "'"])
```